# MongoDB deleted count returns ...?

Tags: mongodb

`db.collection.deleteMany()` returns deletedCount. It is `int` or `long`? The same question about command delete and his result delete.n

Comment: Are you asking in the context of a specific driver or use case? If so, can you provide more detail such as driver version, server version, and how the type affects your use case? The underlying server counters in MongoDB 3.4 are `long long` (64-bit long in C++) but the more precise answer on type depends on how your driver/application interprets the result. For example, numeric values in the JavaScript shell will be a native Number by default (double precision floating point). In practical usage even the limit of 32-bit int seems an ambitious number of documents to delete in a single command.

Comment: To be a little more succinct than the explanation given, this is actually documented on every driver where it would actually matter to the language implementation used. So every strongly typed language implementation does actually have specific documentation for the return structures that tells you exactly what types are used.

Comment: @Stennie I use C# driver. MongoDB version 3.2.10. When i call DeleteManyAsync().DeletedCount on collection, which have documents count more than int.MaxValue, i get negative result. So i check source codes and can't find usages of integer.

Comment: Are you perhaps reading into a variable cast as `int`? Because the [documentation says the count is a `long`.](https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_DeleteResult_DeletedCount.htm)

Comment: @NeilLunn I know about documentation. But in fact there is overflow. Of course i reading into long.

Comment: There is no code in your question. So it is unclear what you are actually doing. The data is stored as a `long`, just like the documentation says. It's more likely your own code is doing something wrong here. Show us the code if you disagree.

Comment: @NeilLunn check it https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2017